# PowerShell - Selecting individual values from column in sub-array

Tags: powershell

I'm working with a PS script that outputs 2 columns - EC2 instance names in col A and EBS volumes in col B. Currently the script is writing all volumes to the same row for that instance (as a sub-array).

Is there a way I can output instance name and then all related volumes before writing the next set?

```
$Instances | select @{n="InstanceId";e={$_}}, @{n="VolumeId";e={((Get-EC2Volume).Attachments | ? InstanceId -eq $_).VolumeId}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your way enumerating the volumeIDs is inefficient but without knowing the properties of `$Instances` or `(Get-EC2Volume).Attachments` this could probaply work:

```
$NewTable = ForEach ($Instance in $Instances){
    (Get-EC2Volume).Attachments | ? InstanceId -eq $Instance | %{
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'Instance' = $Instance
            'Volume'   = $_.VolumeId
        }
    }
}
$NewTable
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're getting something that looks like....

,@{volume1, volume2}

And, you want something that looks like...

volume1
volume2

I think I got this right based on your post:

> ...output instance name and then all related volumes...

Here is my facsimile of your data set:

```
$stuff = @{'box1' = @('v1', 'v2', 'v3'); 'box2' = @('v4', 'v3', 'v9') }
```

I'd do something like this to achieve the look you're after:

```
foreach ($key in $stuff.keys) {
    $key
    $stuff[$key]
}
```

When I try it on my little old machine, this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: thanks - seems I can only vote for 1 answer which I have done for the first to respond.